# How forbid to load script 'Selenium Java' in all browsers

Tags: java, selenium

How forbid to load script  'Selenium Java' in Chrome, Opera, Safari, Mozilla Firefox.
I am want get the page load time with a script and without it.

Comment: The second part of your question does not seem to relate to the first part. Do you want to find a mechanism to block execution of a selenium script? If so you'd have to think about how to implement that: On the client side (e.g, with javascript in the browser) or on the server side.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I doubt Selenium webdriver can run with disabled js in browser.